# When analyzing boost::graph, does one operate on vertex and edge descriptor or their iterators?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, iterator

When working with the BOOST graph library, I have a graph instance fully initialized -- the structure is now static.  I need to do some processing based on the graph.

I'm not clear if I should be working with the iterator types for vertices and edges, or the vertex and edge types themselves?

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperty, EdgeProperty > GraphType;

typedef typename boost::graph_traits< GraphType >::vertex_descriptor VertexType;
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertex_iterator VertexIterator;

typedef typename boost::graph_traits< GraphType >::edge_descriptor   EdgeType;
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::out_edge_iterator EdgeIterator;
```

I have an algorithm where I need to check if two edges are "the same". (in the strongest sense.  Suppose the graph has two parallel edges connecting E1(S1,T2) & E2(S1,T2).  An edge can only be "the same" with at most one of them.

**What's the difference between** `(edge_descriptor == edge_descriptor)` and `(edge_iterator == edge_iterator)`**?**  Same question for vertices.

Most of the graph functions return iterators rather than the edge/vertex types themselves.

I also have the need to store a set of edges.  **Not sure whether I should be storing** `EdgeType` or `EdgeIterator`**?**

```
std::vector<EdgeType>  processedEdges;
std::vector<EdgeIterator>  processedEdges;

vit = std::find( processedEdges.begin(), processedEdges.end(), anotherEdgeRef )
if ( vit == processedEdges.end() )
    doSomethingBasedOnEdgeProperty(*vit);
```

Reference:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html

Comment: If I consider the iterator types generically as "pointer to instance that know how to iterate", then it seems the natural thing to do is work with (eg. operator==) and store iterators.    Obviously, if the graph structure changes, they may be invalid all iterators must be for the same graph instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be storing descriptors, not iterators.

Iterators relate to a logical range, not the graph. Iterators may not be valid between different ranges of the same graph:

```
auto range1 = out_edges(vertex1, g);
auto range2 = out_edges(vertex2, g);

assert(range1.first != range2.first); // unspecified or undefined
```

Instead, descriptors are graph-wide. Depending on graph model, descriptors may be more stable: if an operation invalidates iterators, it doesn't necessarily invalidate the descriptors corresponding to the same graph elements.

In other words, this makes descriptors more usable as vertex or edge "ID" - or, as Boost Graph would call it, `vertex_index` or `edge_index` properties.

I think that is very close to your question.

> One caveat: even so, descriptors may not always be stable!
>
> E.g.:
>
> ```
> adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS>
> ```
>
> leads to vertex descriptors that are stable on append, but not on
>   deletion.
>
> ```
> adjacency_list<setS, listS, directedS>
> ```
>
> on the other hand, leads to vertex descriptors that are stable on both
>   insertion and removal.
>
> See documentation section ["Iterator and Descriptor
>   Stability/Invalidation"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html)

If you need a completely stable identity for your graph elements, you may need to add one as a (bundled) property.

Comment: "Iterators relate to a logical range, not the graph."  That's pretty compelling.
My initial concern about storing descriptors, is not being sure how heavy the descriptors really are.   I'm wondering if I store them in a container, am I also storing copies of the associated properties?  That's more an implementation question.  I was mostly looking to resolve the conceptual difference, which you have helped. :-)
I don't think I need to be worried about stability in this case, because I know the graph structure is fixed at the point code does this processing.

Comment: The descriptors are light by design. As in they are integral (either integer or void* in practice).